# Spring Boot JDBC @Transactional won't rollback

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, transactions

I have implemented a class where i need to insert some data into a database but the insert must rollback if something goes wrong. Once i have performed the insert i throw an exception to test the rollback, but once i check the database, the rows are inserted, which means rollback never happened.

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
public class SomeClass{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Transactional
    public void insertToDb() throws Exception{
        String sql = "INSERT STUFF"
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referring [to the docs for](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) `@Transactional`:

> If no custom rollback rules are configured in this annotation, the transaction will roll back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions.

Since `Exception` is a checked exception, no rollback will be performed by default. You'll either need to throw something that is a (or extends) `RuntimeException`, or list the exception in the `rollbackFor` annotation attribute:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```